# Raty JS not working properly in Vex modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, raty

I have a vex pop up that works properly, however the Raty ratings inside are not working properly.  They are working properly everywhere else on the site, but not in this modal.  The stars show up for you to rate ( all in the same function ) however you cannot click or hover.

Here is my JS function for the Vex modal.

```
$(document).ready ->                                                           
  $("#comment_post").click (event)->
    event.preventDefault();

    vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-plain';
    vex.open
      content: $('.rating-modal').html();
      showCloseButton: false
      escapeButtonCloses: false
      closeClassName: "close-rating"
```

And here is the Raty code

```
$(".user_rating").raty({                                                 
  score: 0,                                                              
  half: true,                                                            
  halfShow: true,                                                        
  click: function( score, evt ) {                                        
    $.ajax({                                                             
      type: 'POST',                                                      
      url: "#{store_rating_create_path}",                                
      data: { rating: score, user_id: "#{current_user.id}", store_id: "#{@store.id}" }                                                                     
    }).done(function (data){});                                          
  }                                                                      
});
```

There are no console errors, I'm not sure what's going on.  The stars show up but they are not functioning.

[image: Raty stars]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have the Raty code inside of the modal Click event. Duh... So it was originally loading on Doc ready, so it had already been fired by the time I fired the modal and the modal needed it to be fired again.  So I moved the code inside the modal click function and all is well.